# Rails Error: ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication

I am getting this error: `ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken` on every single post request on my webapp.

My temporary solution is adding this to the controller: `skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token` but of course the creates a vulnerability...

Does any one know why I might be getting this error, so I can fix it without creating a vulnerability?

Thank you.

Comment: How do you make post requests?

Comment: Using regular html. Is that why? I need to use rails? How do I do that?

Comment: Can you post your console output into your post? Also, as well as any other controllers that is affecting your POST requests?

Comment: What Rails version are you using at the moment?

Comment: Do you have a CSRF meta tag? Are you using the Rails form helpers so that the CSRF tag is included in the form parameters? Do you have some sort of caching that might result in a stale CSRF token being sent to the client?

Comment: I do not have a CSRF meta tag. How do I add that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to send authenticate token with your HTTP call to controller. Normally if you are using `form_for` helper then you don't need to send authenticity token explicitly. But if you using HTML form `<form>` or Ajax request then you must send this token with you call.

**Ajax**

```
$.ajax({  
.....,  
beforeSend: function(xhr) {xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'))},  
....... });
```

**Form**  put this inside html form tag

```
<%= tag(:input, :type => "hidden", :name => request_forgery_protection_token.to_s, :value => form_authenticity_token) %>
```

Comment: I have a question that doesn't completly relate to this. But is there a way that a user could forge of form and submit a fake one, by for example changing the value of the max in a number input? If so how can I prevent that or do AuthenticityTokens do all that already?

Comment: Also when you say put this inside html form tag, where exactly is that?

Just <form action="something" method="post" <%= tag(:input, :type => "hidden", :name => request_forgery_protection_token.to_s, :value => form_authenticity_token) %> >

Comment: @Pabi read this http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/RequestForgeryProtection.html